# Playing MediaStore.Audio.Media Entries

Tags: android

I'm writing an app that can play all audio files present in MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.
Here's a bit of what I have so far:

```
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String uri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

        // Use uri to play music...

    }
```

And this works fine. I'm able to play the audio by passing the uri to a MediaPlayer.
However...

1. MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA has no guarantees of holding a uri. To my understanding, it can hold absolutely anything.
2. MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA is deprecated.

Is there any way to play the audio items in external storage, without relying on MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. 
You can simply play it with the `ContentUris.withAppendedId`, as `MediaPlayer` has a [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setDataSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)) for playing content by `Uri`.
Here, for example, i'm setting the song Uri.

```java
/// Helper function
public static Uri getSongUri(int songId) {
   return ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, songId);
}

/// And then...
public void setUri(Context appContext, int songId) {
    // ....
    player.setDataSource(appContext, getSongUri(songId));
    // ....
}
```